# Attempting to connect to SQL Server in VS / SSDT to edit DTSX / SSIS process, "Invalid Class String"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm attempting to edit an existing .dtsx file (SSIS package).

I've got Visual Studio 2019 and the SQL Server Integration Services Project extension installed.

I create a new Integration Services Project, create a Connection to my SQL Server, then because I'm trying to edit existing SSIS packages, I want to import the current ones from SQL Server. So I go to "SSIS Packages" in the Solution Explorer, right click, Add Existing Package.

Change "Package Location" to SQL Server, leave Windows Authentication on, then I go to navigate to the file location and I get an error message saying simply "Invalid Class String"

When I go to more details, I get the following:

```
Invalid class string


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.GetPackageInfos(String strFolder, String serverName, String serverUserName, String serverPassword)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.ServerPackagesForm.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<CreateSqlServerEnumerationForm>b__0(String path)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.ServerPackagesForm.CreateForm(PackageInfosGetter packageEnumerator, String serverName, Boolean openExisting, String defaultName)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.ServerPackagesForm.CreateSqlServerEnumerationForm(String serverName, String user, String pwd, Boolean openExisting, String defaultName)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.PackageLocationControl.buttonBrowse_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

===================================

Invalid class string


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.GetPackageInfos(String bstrPackageFolder, String bstrServerName, String bstrServerUserName, String bstrServerPassword)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.GetPackageInfos(String strFolder, String serverName, String serverUserName, String serverPassword)
```

Anybody know what the issue is?

Comment: What is the version of the target SQL Server? You could be missing "Microsoft SQL Server NNNN Management Objects", "Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server NNNN" or other version-specific dependencies from your local Windows installation.

Comment: SQL Server 2016